# How can I attach gps chip to 3g chips?

Tags: gps, tcp-ip

I'm a software developer. Recently, my bike was stolen and I'm pissed off.

The police is useless and what's in my mind now is how can I prevent this from happening again.

What I want to do is, lets say I have a gps chip which can collect the geography data, and this chip is attached to a 3g chip which is used to send data. When I'm doing cycling, I'll generate power and stored in the battery.

So every 30 secs, the 3g chip sends out the data.

So first of all, is it feasible? Secondly, What kind of hardware do I need to buy?

Comment: GPS tracking is too late if what you want to "prevent" your bicycle from being stolen. Rather, it is a "cure" to help you in recovery. The solution you are hatching is complex... instead, the Bicycle Law states: All bicycles weigh 25 kilograms.

A 15kg bicycle needs a 10kg lock. A 20kg bicycle needs a 5kg lock. A 25kg bicycle doesn't need a lock.

Perhaps, a 10kg lock is in order.

Comment: That comment makes no sense.  Worst comment response to a question I have seen yet.

Comment: The most interesting part is how to hide it, since the thief may just disconnect it. It's certainly feasible to do this and might start with something like this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7917

Comment: What you're describing is called a "smartphone". You can get them really cheap if they're not latest-generation Android or iPhone, and the GPS and telephony connections already work.

Comment: Sounds like next time instead of just a stolen bicycle, you'll have a bicycle, GPS receiver, 3g modem, and battery stolen.

Comment: The point of my previous comment, Mr. @TobyLawrence, is that the GPS contraption is no substitute for a bicycle lock. The wisdom of the Bicycle Law is that the more expensive your bike (the more lighter it is/advanced alloys or carbon composite), the more elaborate the locks that you need.

Comment: @Madmanguruman Yes, that's what I am thinking as well. I want to create a portable, hard to break device which can be hided somewhere in the bike. It should consume very little battery.

Comment: @shimofuri definately the rules should be updated. The ones who make rules still live in the ancient society

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear on whether you want to build your own device (in which case the question belongs here), or are looking for shopping suggestions or search help for the many such products commercially available: [1](http://www.sanav.com/gps_tracking/CT-24.htm), [2](http://www.meitrack.net/gps-gprs-tracker), [3](http://www.trackingtheworld.com/wtgprs.htm), [4](http://dx.com/p/portable-mini-gsm-gprs-gps-tracker-for-personal-remote-positioning-22599).

Clearly, from the example products above, it is *feasible*.